# variable for field separator in perl

Tags: perl, awk

In awk I can write: `awk -F: 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} ...'`

In Perl, what's the equivalent of `FS`? I'd like to write

```
perl -F: -lane 'BEGIN {$, = [what?]} ...'
```

---

update with an example:

```
echo a:b:c:d | awk -F: 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {$2 = 42; print}'
echo a:b:c:d | perl -F: -ane 'BEGIN {$, = ":"} $F[1] = 42; print @F'
```

Both output `a:42:c:d`

I would prefer not to hard-code the `:` in the Perl BEGIN block, but refer to wherever the `-F` option saves its argument.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with awk... can you provide an example of what you're trying to accomplish with perl? I can probably answer that better than an awk->perl question. I gather that OFS is theoutput field separator (which you correctly identified as $, in perl), and FS is the input? field separator?  I don't think perl has such a concept... although maybe split()'s functionality is similar, however it doesn't have a default "separator"--it must be provided directly.

Comment: The parameter to `-F` is actually a regex, not a literal string, so I don't think it's directly accessible by any special variable.

Comment: I think you would get better answers if you actually said what you wanted to accomplish, instead of alluding to various other commands/programs and how they work.

Comment: @TLP, I want to know if there is an "input field separator" variable in Perl -- I didn't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To sum up, what I'm looking for does not exist:

1. there's no variable that holds the argument for `-F`, and more importantly
2. Perl's "FS" is fundamentally a different data type (regular expression) than the "OFS" (string) -- it does not make sense to join a list of strings using a regex.

Note that the same holds true in awk: `FS` is a string but acts as regex:

```sh
echo a:b,c:d | awk -F'[:,]' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {$2=42; print}'
```

outputs "`a[:,]42[:,]c[:,]d`"

Thanks for the insight and workarounds though.

---

You can use perl's `-s` (similar to awk's `-v`) to pass a "FS" variable, but the `split` becomes manual:

```sh
echo a:b:c:d | perl -sne '
    BEGIN {$, = $FS}
    @F = split $FS;
    $F[1] = 42;
    print @F;
' -- -FS=":"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the exact length of input, you could do this:

```
echo a:b:c:d | perl -F'(:)' -ane '$, = $F[1]; @F = @F[0,2,4,6]; $F[1] = 42; print @F'
```

If the input is of variable lengths, you'll need something more sophisticated than @f[0,2,4,6].

**EDIT:** -F seems to simply provide input to an automatic split() call, which takes a complete RE as an expression. You may be able to find something more suitable by reading the perldoc entries for **split**, **perlre**, and **perlvar**.

Comment: A generic way to get only the even-indexed elements: `@F = @F[grep {$_%2==0} (0..$#F)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can *sort of* cheat it, because perl is actually using the `split` function with your `-F` argument, and you can tell `split` to preserve what it splits on by including capturing parens in the regex:

```
$ echo a:b:c:d | perl -F'(:)' -ane 'print join("/", @F);'
a/:/b/:/c/:/d
```

You can see what perl's doing with some of these "magic" command-line arguments by using `-MO=Deparse`, like this:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -F'(:)' -ane 'print join("/", @F);'
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    our(@F) = split(/(:)/, $_, 0);
    print join('/', @F);
}
-e syntax OK
```

You'd have to change your `@F` subscripts to double what they'd normally be (`$F[2] = 42`).

Answer (score 1):

Darnit...

The best I can do is:

```
echo a:b:c:d | perl -ne '$v=":";@F = split("$v"); $F[1] = 42; print join("$v", @F) . "\n";'
```

You don't need the `-F:` this way, and you're only stating the colon once. I was hoping there was someway of setting variables on the command line like you can with Awk's `-v` switch.

For one liners, Perl is usually not as clean as Awk, but I remember using Awk before I knew of Perl and writing 1000+ line Awk scripts.

Trying things like this made people think Awk was either named after the sound someone made when they tried to decipher such a script, or stood for AWKward.

Comment: I was taking a trip down memory lane, and it struck me you *can* set variables from the cmd line: with the hacky `-s` switch: `echo a:b:c:d | perl -sne '@F = split("$sep"); $F[1] = 42; print join("$sep", @F) . "\n";' -- -sep=:`

Answer (score 0):

There is no input record separator in Perl.  You're basically emulating awk by using the `-a` and `-F` flags.  If you really don't want to hard code the value, then why not just use an environmental variable?

```
$ export SPLIT=":"
$ perl -F$SPLIT -lane 'BEGIN { $, = $ENV{SPLIT}; } ...'
```